# Simpson's Rule over [-3,3]

Tags: numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

To Find $I = \int_{-3}^3 \sin x^4 dx$ using the Simpson's (Parabolic) rule with $n=6$ intervals.

$h=\frac{b-a}{n}=\frac{3-(-3)}{6}=1$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline x\rightarrow&x_0&x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&x_6\\ \hline&-3&-2&-1&0&1&2&3\\ \hline y=\sin x^4\rightarrow&-0.629&-0.287&0.841&0&0.841&-0.287&-0.629\\ \hline &y_0&y_1&y_2&y_3&y_4&y_5&y_6\\ \hline \end{array}

According to the [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule):

$I = \frac{h}{3}[y_0+y_6+2(y_1+y_3+y_5)+4(y_2+y_4)] $

$I = \frac{1}{3}[-0.629-0.629)+2(-0.287+0-0.287)+4(0.841+0.841)] = -0.0657$

So the result with the Simpson's method is -0.0657. But the actual value of the integral is 0.67946. The result with [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simpson%27s%20rule%20sin%20(x%5E4)%20on%20%5B-3,3%5D%20with%20interval%20size%201) is 0.294673.

Do we need to break the interval at x=0 in [-3,0] and [0,3] and add the two results?

Comment: This function oscillates wildly (draw the graph!). With so few intervals, one cannot expect an accurate estimate to the integral.

Comment: Yes, I see that it oscillates wildly. So can we guess the approximate value of n (number of intervals) for a good result?

Answer (score 2):

[The error in approximating an integral using Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Error) is

$$-\dfrac{1}{90}\left(\dfrac{b-a}{2}\right)^5 f^{(4)}(\xi)
=-2.7 f^{(4)}(\xi)$$

for some $\xi \in [a, b]$.

$$\dfrac{d^4}{dx^4}(\sin x^4) = 16(16 x^8 - 51) x^4\sin(x^4) + 8(3-144x^8)\cos(x^4)$$

So, at $\xi=2.9$ (for example), $-2.7 f^{(4)}(\xi) = -2.4484×10^8$

Of course, this only indicates that the error **could be** a really large number but it does say that using Simpson's rule in this case is a bad idea.